# Am I violating best practice by having an xml element that has an attribute but no data?

Tags: xml, attributes, schema, element

I'm saving UI user preferences in an XML file.

[image]

The XML elements I'm using to store the state of these two UI elements are, e.g.,

```
  <always-show-checked-schema-names-in-filtered-treeview checked="True" />
  <always-show-checked-table-names-in-filtered-treeview checked="False" />
```

Am I violating best practice by having an xml element that has an attribute but no data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is perfectly sound practice to use an element that has attributes and no content. There are many XML vocabularies that work this way.

For example, some vocabularies use a design principle that text nodes should only be used for content that is intended to be seen by human readers, while all content that is primarily intended for machine processing (or that is considered to be "metadata") should be in attributes. Your vocabulary might not have such a principle, but it might have other design principles that are equally sound and that lead to similar results.